# Why bootstrap override internal style?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is my Head tag in a html page

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style>
        input[type=text] {
            font-size: 18px;
            height: auto;
        }
        select {
            font-size: 18px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

bootstrap override my inline style for select element,
What is the reason?

Comment: First of all, that is not an “inline style” – that term means styles set via the `style` _attribute_ directly on an element. And your style here probably gets overwritten, because bootstrap uses a more specific selector.

Comment: You should add HTML of the elements Bootstrap overriding style of! or create JSFiddle

Comment: @CBroe It was a verbal mistake, I corrected.

Comment: try to add `!important` to your style, eg:  `font-size: 18px !important;`

Comment: @SimoneNigro: That’s rather bad advice. `!important` will lead to problems, if you need to override those styles later on in a more specific context.

Comment: target full path like (.from-control  input[type=text] {})

Answer (score 0):

Rule `.form-control` in bootstrap is more weighty than your `input`
just use `.form-control` and add new style

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap select styled with other elements like input,textarea etc.

The `.form-control` class name more specific and takes precedence then select element that's why its better to use  `.form-control` class to override bootstrap default style.

Use  `.form-control` instead of select element.Add this class to your CSS.